# How to prevent excess whitespace after line breaks in inline equations using symbols defined in a glossary?

Tags: math-mode, glossaries, inline, white-space

I have several mathematical symbols with definitions in a glossary created using the [`glossaries`](https://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries) package. As an example,

```
\newglossaryentry{real}
{
    sort={r0},
    name={\ensuremath{\mathbb{R}}},
    description={The field of real numbers}
}
```

However, when a line break occurs after a binary operator or relation, for example in the equation `$\mathbf{M} \in \gls{real}[^{n \times n}]$`, the horizontal space after the relation is not omitted as usual, but added to the next line instead.

Is there any way to prevent the insertion of additional whitespace? Treating the entire equation as an atom to prevent line breaks, i.e., by adding curly braces `${\mathbf{M} \in \gls{real}[^{n \times n}]}$`, may be an option in some cases, but not generally.

Any solution should retain both the clickable link to the definition, and the glossary entry itself.

Here is a full-fledged minimal working example showing the issue

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[xindy]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{real}
{
    sort={r0},
    name={\ensuremath{\mathbb{R}}},
    description={The field of real numbers}
}

\begin{document}
Just some useless text to cause a line break followed by random abc $\mathbf{M} \in \gls{real}[^{n \times n}]$ and even more text here so the line is filled appropriately.
Note the excess whitespace before \gls{real}.

Just some useless text to cause a line break followed by random abc ${\mathbf{M} \in \gls{real}[^{n \times n}]}$ and even more text here so the line is filled appropriately.
Note that treating it as an atom causes an overfull hbox.

Just some useless text to cause a line break followed by random abc $\mathbf{M} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and even more text here so the line is filled appropriately.
Note the lack of excess whitespace and linking before \gls{real} when the symbol is used directly.

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps, `\glsentrytext{real}` is the better way here...

Comment: That pretty much removes any advantage of using a glossary reference at all.

Comment: Depends on what you need -- do you need a link, or the do you really need an entry in the glossary?

Comment: I really need an entry in the glossary AND I want to keep "jump-to-defintion" link.

Comment: Please provide a compilable document then where your issue occurs, not just the bare glossary entry  definition

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Added a MWE.

Comment: `\in` is a binary relation, not a binary operator.

Comment: @AriBrodsky aside from the different spacing, I don't think the distinction matters much in this case, but I adjusted the question correspondingly.

Comment: If you are willing to add breaks by hand, use `$\mathbf{M} \in$ $\gls{real}[^{n \times n}]$`.

Comment: @JohnKormylo That would introduce a normal text space instead of the skip used by the relation, I.e., it changes the spacing.

Comment: How about ` $\mathbf{M} \in \mbox{\gls{real}[^{n \times n}]}$`?

Comment: @JohnKormylo that causes a bunch of "missing $ inserted" errors.

Comment: Oops, didn't notice.  \mathmbox from mathtools works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a workaround that appears to work for my use cases: Wrap the binary relation itself in curly braces `{}` to prevent the automatic addition of thick spaces. Then add the thick spaces `\;` and the `\allowbreak` back in manually:

```
$\mathbf{M}\;{\in}\allowbreak\;\gls{real}[^{n \times n}]$
```

This breaks (and renders) correctly. For binary operators, use `\:` instead of `\;` If someone has a cleaner solution that applies everywhere automatically instead of requiring a local workaround, that would, of course, be better.